# Do male Blanks exist in the 40K universe?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Throughout the books I have read I have only seen examples of female Blanks throughout the 40K universe, the Sisters of Silence being one example.

Are there any male Blanks in any of the source material?

Comment: Yes atleast multiple members (I believe even the founder) of the Culexus temple of the assassinorum where male.

Comment: If i remember correctly the reason that male blanks are rarer is that the pariah gene is carried on the X chromosome meaning that females are almost twice as likely to have a copy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Yes

The wikia page for [Blanks](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Blank) lists a few possible characters. Among those is [Ferik Jurgen](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Ferik_Jurgen).

> Despite his unprepossessing physical appearance, his indefatigable body odour, and general lack of basic social skills, he had several qualities which made him indispensable to Cain, most notably his fierce bravery and unwavering loyalty to Cain, the Guard, and the Emperor, his implacability under the worst of conditions (except flying), and, last but not least, his incredibly rare attributes as a Blank, which saved both Cain and several others from Daemonic and psychic attack innumerable times.

Jurgen's status is confirmed in the epilogue of the first Cain novel, [*For the Emperor*](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/For_the_Emperor_(Novel)), in a discussion between Cain and Inquisitor Amberley Vail:

> "You think Jurgen's a psyker?" ... Amberley shook her head.
>
> "No, quite the reverse. He's a blank, I'm sure of it." ... "Blanks are like anti-psykers," she explained. "They can't be affected by psykers or warp entities. They block telepathic communication. You saw how the patriarch reacted to him...."
>
> "That explains a lot," I said, recalling a number of incidents over the years which had seemed no more than mildly puzzling at the time, but which I now realised formed a pattern, confirming my aide's resistance to psychic attack. "How long have you known?"
>
> "Since the first time I saw him," she admitted. "When Rakel [a sanctioned psyker] had a seizure when he was trying to help her...."

(*For the Emperor*, Epilogue, p. 269 in the omnibus edition *Hero of the Imperium*.)

Answer (score 8):

#### They sure do, but in the fluff for whatever reason, they're very rare.

[**Inquisitor Gideon Ravenor**](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Gideon_Ravenor)'s blank is a man named Wystan Frauka.

> a man with the latent ability to block out psychic activity. Big, chain-smoking and disliked by pretty much everyone (in part because of his psychic blankness. It was mentioned in Xenos that the field untouchables project also creates a sense of fear, revulsion and dread in others.). An interesting difference to the Eisenhorn novels is Frauka's so-called inhibitor, a device allowing him to shut down his natural anti-psi field. He is often found passing the time by reading pornographic data-slates or staring at the female members of the team.

And I'll assume you have not read this particular series of books? You definitely should, in my humble opinion, the [**Inquisitor**](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Inquisitor_(Novel_Series)) series is up there with the very best 40k stuff.

Comment: It's half the reason to read ANY 40k stuff. Most of the 40k stuff is pretty campy and mediocre, you'd only read it because you're a 40k fan. But Abnett's stuff is good even if you're not a 40k fan. I got my MOM to read his books. (By the way, the other half of the reason to read any 40k stuff is shared between Gaunt's Ghosts and Ciaphas Cain.)

Comment: @Harabeck and The Last Chancers too, if you haven't read them, they're great. Same vein as everything you've mentioned!

Comment: I'll have to give those a read.